"Like" Button on SharePoint Page Analytics Not Persisting
I'm facing an issue with the "like" button feature in the page analytics section of our SharePoint site. When I interact with the "Do you like using page analytics?" button, it seems to register my input. However, when I navigate away and return to the analytics page, the like count doesn't appear to persist, as if my interaction wasn't recorded.
To troubleshoot, I've tried the following:

Clearing the browser cache and cookies

Using different browsers and devices


Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I was expecting the like count to be saved and reflected accurately upon revisiting the page. Any insights or solutions to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated!
